# Why is the font Fontin sharp on the browser but very smooth on the PDF Reader?

Tags: css, html, browser, fonts

I liked a font called Fontin, so I decided to use it on my site. I'm using this code:

```
<div style='font-family: "Fontin"'>Text here</div>
```

Those are what I'm seeing:

[image: FireFox]

[image: PDF]

Very different. What is going on there?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Adobe Reader font smoothing. 
You can disable / enable it via Edit->Accessibility->Setup Assistant (Select "Set all accessibility options", click on next and check / uncheck "Disable text smoothing").

To get the same effect on firefox (with html5 / css3) use -webkit-font-smoothing:

```
<div style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;"> Smooth Text ;) </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different font rendering engines. Firefox uses Direct2D (in combination with ClearType if you're on Windows) while Adobe use their own engine. Among other things, Adobe's engine uses a lot of smoothing or anti-aliasing compared to browsers. You can modify firefox's font-smoothing with this addon https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/. I also believe changing the options to disable hardware acceleration might change the font rendering.